# Getting different RMSEs from one PCA model

Tags: r, pca

I'm getting different RMSE values from a same PCA regression model, but I can't seem to figure out why. Here's my code, using the data set `Hitters` from R package `ISLR`.

```
hitters <- na.omit(Hitters)
set.seed(1)
train <- sample(x = seq(263), 
                size = 180, 
                replace = FALSE)
pca.fit2 <- pcr(Salary ~ ., 
                data = hitters, 
                scale = TRUE,
                validation = "CV",
                subset = train)
validationplot(pca.fit2, val.type = "RMSEP")
```

[image: RMSE against number of principal components]

From the image, I eyeball a RMSE of about 290 at 7 principal components. But when I calculated the RMSE manually, I didn't get anything near 290.

```
pca.pred <- predict(pca.fit2, hitters[train, ], ncomp = 7)
sqrt(mean((pca.pred - hitters[train, ]$Salary)^2))
[1] 277.3104
```

Is there anything wrong with my code or my understanding of RMSE for PCA?